# ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package when using Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to `dev` a package I already have locally installed because I am updating my Julia version.

```
Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package NameOfPackage [980c2a51]:
 NameOfPackage [980c2a51] log:
 ├─ NameOfPackage [980c2a51] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by NameOfOtherPackage [e09632b2] — no versions left
```

However, when I do `] st`, I get `[afad1059] NameOfPackage v0.2.0 [~/.julia/dev/NameOfPackage]`

How can `NameOfPackage` have no known versions but show a version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a UUID mismatch (one UUID starts with “980c” and one with “afad”) so this looks like two different packages to the resolver. You need to figure out which is the correct one and remove all traces of the wrong UUID.